# How to get performance_metrics() on weekly frequency in facebook-prophet?

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

[I am working with `prophet`](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) library for educational purpose on a classic dataset:
the [air passenger dataset available on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yasserh/air-passengers-forecast-dataset).

Data are on monthly frequency which is not possible to cross validate as standard frequency on Prophet, [based on that discussion](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1672).

During the cross validation for Time Series I used the `prophet` function `cross_validation()` passing the arguments on weekly frequency.

But when I call the function `performance_metrics` it returns the horizion column on daily frequency.

**How can I get on weekly frequency?**

I also tried to read the documentation and the [function description](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/e665430adcd7690a1ea7565803f34043596045fe/python/prophet/diagnostics.py#L318):

> Metrics are calculated over a rolling window of cross validation
> predictions, after sorting by horizon. Averaging is first done within each
> value of horizon, and then across horizons as needed to reach the window
> size. The size of that window (number of simulated forecast points) is
> determined by the rolling_window argument, which specifies a proportion of
> simulated forecast points to include in each window. rolling_window=0 will
> compute it separately for each horizon. The default of rolling_window=0.1
> will use 10% of the rows in df in each window. rolling_window=1 will
> compute the metric across all simulated forecast points. The results are
> set to the right edge of the window.

Here how I modelled the dataset:

```
model = Prophet()
model.fit(df)
future_dates = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=36, freq='MS')

df_cv = cross_validation(model, 
                         initial='300 W', 
                         period='5 W', 
                         horizon = '52 W')
df_cv.head()
```

[image]

And then when I call the `performance_metrics`

```
df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv)
df_p.head()
```

This is the output that I get with a daily frequency.
[image]

I am probably missing something or I made a mistake in the code.